# How to send a broadcast packet with specific format using Python

Tags: python, sockets, python-2.7, python-3.x

I need to send a request broadcast packet to 255.255.255.255 port 1000
I don't know how to send 0x01 as first byte and the following 4 bytes is a random number.
Thanks you all, in advance
    import socket
    import sys

```
def main(message) :
    my_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    my_socket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_BROADCAST,1)
    my_socket.sendto(message, ('255.255.255.255' ,10000))
    my_socket.close()

if len(sys.argv) < 2 :
    sys.exit('wrong args')
else :    
        main(sys.argv[1])
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

From the docs, here is a function that sends a message out on a socket:

```
def mysend(self, msg):
        totalsent = 0
        while totalsent < MSGLEN:
            sent = self.sock.send(msg[totalsent:])
            if sent == 0:
                raise RuntimeError("socket connection broken")
            totalsent = totalsent + sent
```

The sending code here is usable for almost any messaging scheme - **in Python you send strings**

So you just need to build the string by prefixng it with '0x01'